# PHP socket server takes a lot of CPU usage

Tags: php, sockets

I follow some tutorial [(1)](http://devzone.zend.com/209/writing-socket-servers-in-php/), [(2)](http://endyourif.com/how-to-create-a-socket-server-in-php/) on internet to create a PHP socket server, and it works quite well. There is only thing is my PHP script takes a lot of CPU usage (99%).

I do not show code here, because my code is similar to the above tutorials.

The main action is written in an infinitive loop

```
while (true)
{
   $this->selectChangedSockets();
   $this->handleNewClients();
   $this->receiveInput();
   $this->checkDisconnections();
}
```

The functions inside the my loop are just to handle inputs (new client's connection, client's message, etc.), and handle outputs (send back to the client's message, etc.)

My php script is always on top in CPU usage (99%). I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914880/php-showing-97-of-cpu-usage), and they suggest to put "sleep(1)" in the loop. My socket server is for the real time applications, and I am not sure this is a good way to go?

Anyone who has experience with php socket can give me any suggestion?

Is there any standard php socket server library?
or do I need to run the script in the background?

**Updated**

Because you mention the function socket_select may pause a little bit, I give you my code:

```
    private function selectChangedSockets()
    {
        // Reset array of changed sockets
        $this->changed = array_merge(array($this->socket), $this->clients);

        $null = null;
        $res = socket_select($this->changed, $null, $null, 0);
        if (false === $res)
        {
            echo "socket_select() failed, reason: " .
                socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        while (true) {

            $this->selectChangedSockets();
            //$this->handleNewClients();
            //$this->receiveInput();
            //$this->checkDisconnections();
        }
    }
```

My PHP script still takes 99% CPU usage.

Comment: I'd suggest **not** using an infinite loop, they use a lot of memory, stops a page loading etc and is generally something to avoid doing...

Comment: so, what will you suggest me to do?

Comment: Run your code in a cron, try looking at something like [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-cron-jobs-with-php--net-19428) (but without the loop)

Comment: so, for each second, I need to re-create all things (socket connection, mysql connection, all variables) ? I don't think it's a good approach to go.

Comment: Why not create a single mysql instance then? Namely, `$link = mysqli_init(); $link->real_connect("localhost", "dbUsername", "dbPassword", "dbName");` or are the sockets a dead set necessity?

Comment: Try adding a `usleep(100);` call at the end of the loop. I think your problem is that you're in an infinite loop that never pauses, so you're doing everything all the time without a break. Give the processor a chance to do something else for a moment

Comment: Also @chipbk10, please add your code, linking to tutorials does not help to get you an answer, it adds noise to the community and does nothing for a resolution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `selectChangedSockets` method should be blocking, meaning, not return until there are changes on the sockets. See [`socket_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php).

A `while ( true ) {}` will use 100% CPU time. You will need some kind of delay.
Since you can use `socket_select`, you can specify a timeout there, using 0% CPU time until there is actually some work to be done:

```
function selectChangedSockets() {
    $read   = array($socket1, $socket2);   // array of your sockets
    $write  = NULL;
    $except = NULL;
    $num_changed_sockets = socket_select($read, $write, $except, NULL);
}
```

This will wait until one of the sockets in `$read` has data available. For a server socket, this happens when a new connection is established by a client. For a connected socket, this happens when the client has sent data.

Again, see [`socket_select`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-select.php) for details and examples. Especially the first user contributed note, which uses a `while (true)`, handles new connections, and reads data from clients.

Note however, from the socket_select page, about the 4th parameter:

> tv_sec may be zero , causing socket_select() to return immediately. This is useful for polling. If tv_sec is NULL (no timeout), socket_select() can block indefinitely.

Comment: no, even I comment all these functions. My script still takes 99% CPU usage.

Comment: @chipbk10 Well, if your call to socket_select is blocking, you shouldn't have 99% cpu usage, as the process should be just paused waiting for notification. You need to add a small example that actually shows the issue, and not the calls to your methods that may have any random implementations that we don't know about.

Comment: I do not believe this is an answer, you do not attempt to answer the question, but pose one to the OP, please consider removing this and adding as a comment

Comment: @SamSwift웃 You're right, I was trying to be efficient ;-) I did answer the question though - everything after the `?`. ;-)

Comment: useful information about socket_select. Let's me check on it.

Comment: I've updated my code. Unfortunately, my script still takes almost 99% CPU usage

Comment: What does the `socket_select` call return? If it returns `false` you can use `socket_last_error()` to see what's wrong. Is the server socket `listen`ing?

Comment: Updated my code. The server is still listening, and take 99% CPU usage.

Comment: My bad - the last (timeout) parameter must be NULL, not 0. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

if socket server idle 5 second (not receive data), idle mode, relaxes CPU,

```
<?php

if (!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0))) {
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
}

$server_idle=time();
while (1) {

    $buf="";
    $r = socket_recvfrom($sock, $buf, 512, MSG_DONTWAIT, $remote_ip, $remote_port);
    if ($buf) {
        $server_idle=time();

    //socket process codes
    //.
    //.

    }



    if (time()-$server_idle>5) {  // if Server idle 5 second; IDLE Mode!
        usleep(100);  // IDLE Mode
    } else {
        // usleep(1); // No IDLE Mode usleep(1) milisecond less CPU process
    }

}

?>
```